# Write an efficient algorithm to divide the tree into connected components with at most V/2 vertices

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm referring to the link below to try and write an algorithm to find a vertex in a tree so that removing that vertex gives connected components with the size of each component being at most V/2 vertices.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742440/you-can-always-delete-a-vertex-from-a-tree-g-such-that-the-remaining-connected

I do understand the proof given in the accepted answer which uses arrows to find that vertex. I can't quite figure out how to write an algorithm for the same.

Comment: but it's not about deleting a vertex, it's about deleting an edge

Comment: @mangusta, its about deleting a vertex.

Comment: @trincot I don't mean the given problem itself, I mean that if we remove a vertex which is itself a connected component, then talking about `dividing the tree` makes little sense because the tree gets reduced in size, not divided

Comment: @mangusta Right, removing all edges incident to that vertex.

Comment: @mangusta I'm not sure if I understtand you correctly, but we're talking about deleting a single vertex so that we get connected components T-v

Answer (score 0):

I will just explain the proof and then later on give the pseudo code so that you can understand the psuedo code easily. The vertex that you are looking for is called **centroid**. So basically we need to find the centroid of the tree.

First of all this needs to be clear that there can be only one node that satisfies this property.

Let the given tree be T. Start from any vertex claiming to be the required vertex. Then check whether this is true or not. If this is the required vertex then nothing needs to be done. If this is **not** the vertex then select the next vertex adjacent to the current vertex that is the part of the subtree which had more than n/2 vertices in it. Repeat the process until you find the answer.

Now the pseudo code. Here are the meaning of the variables used.

v_centroid stores the centroid

v[i] stores the list of all nodes that are connected to i

size[i] stores the size of subtree of i.

```
v_centroid = any vertex
dfs(v_centroid,parent)   // v_centroid is the assumed centroid and parent is parent of the node processing. For initial call you can use -1 as parent or any other undefined value suitable.
v_centroid = findCentroid(v_centroid,v_centroid)


func dfs(int node, int parent) 
    size[node] := 1
    for i in v[node] 
        if(*i not equals parent) 
            dfs(*i, node)
            size[node] = size[node] + size[parent]
        end if
    end for
end func

func findCentroid(int node, int parent) 
    for i in v[node]
        if(i not equals parent and size[i]>MAX_SIZE/2)
            return findCentroid(i, node)
        end if
    end for
    return node
end func
```